# How to perform a count fetch request on the background

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, core-data

How can I perform a count request on the background, the code below is heavily blocking my UI. I tried to implement `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest` but I wasn't able to put it together. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
        let NewMessage: NSFetchRequest<Mesages> = Mesages.fetchRequest()

        NewMessage.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timestamp = %@", date)

        do {
           //context.fetch blocking the main thread
            let checkMessages = try context.fetch(NewMessage)
            if checkMessages.count == 0 {

             print('no duplicates')

            }
        } catch  {
        }
```

Comment: try to create a private queue context chil of the persistent store. Don't use as context  the main context or a child of the main context

Answer (score 1):

Use **PrivateQueueConcurrencyType** to local managed object and use countForFetchRequest method instead of fetch :

```
let context: NSManagedObjectContext =   NSManagedObjectContext.init(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
// set context with parent child hierarchy.
let NewMessage: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "Message")
var error:NSError? ;

let messagesCount = context.countForFetchRequest(NewMessage, error:&error)
print(messagesCount)
```